# When i integrate recaptcha-enterprise into iOS with cocoapods,something is wrong with arm64, how to solve it

Tags: ios, recaptcha-enterprise

pod 'RecaptchaEnterprise','17.0.0', :source => "https://cpdc-eap.googlesource.com/RecaptchaEnterprise.git"

cocoapods is success, but xcode show the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_JSObjectIsFunction", referenced from:
iosguard::IsCallableJSValue(JSValue*) in recaptcha(utils_20e35588790c00941fa61c0ddccd0959.o)
"_JSObjectIsConstructor", referenced from:
iosguard::IsCallableJSValue(JSValue*) in recaptcha(utils_20e35588790c00941fa61c0ddccd0959.o)
"_JSValueGetType", referenced from:
iosguard::GetJSValueType(JSValue*) in recaptcha(utils_20e35588790c00941fa61c0ddccd0959.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_JSValue", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in recaptcha(javascript_executor_15c839bc58faec3ce2d75d61fa34786b.o)
objc-class-ref in recaptcha(native_conversions_906021188aa773e592eb340a130f2626.o)
"_JSValueIsObject", referenced from:
iosguard::IsCallableJSValue(JSValue*) in recaptcha(utils_20e35588790c00941fa61c0ddccd0959.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_JSContext", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in recaptcha(IGDContainer_7c03e8f54879222dddd9c24d310f8237.o)
objc-class-ref in recaptcha(javascript_executor_15c839bc58faec3ce2d75d61fa34786b.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: HI, so trying to implement the same, But I am unable to access https://cpdc-eap.googlesource.com/RecaptchaEnterprise.git repo as in document - https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps

Please help how do I get access for this

Answer (score 0):

As a note, it works fine for me with version `18.1.0` ([Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps))

Seems that the support for M1 simulators (arm64) was added back in May, 2022 ([Release notes](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/download-ios-sdk-preview?hl=es-419))